# Importing "ExtendedAppiumLibrary" failed (Robot framework)

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I downloaded the ExtendedAppiumLibrary using

```
pip install robotframework-extendedappiumlibrary
```

After downloading, I tried to import "ExtendedAppiumLibrary" in my project and its giving me the following error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>ride.py
FAILED ExtendedAppiumLibrary Initializing test library 'ExtendedAppiumLibrary' with no arguments failed: ValueError: Invalid time string 'Capture Page Scre
enshot'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 184, in _get_instance
    return libcode(*self.positional_args, **self.named_args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ExtendedAppiumLibrary\__init__.py", line 78, in __init__
    AppiumLibrary.__init__(self, run_on_failure)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AppiumLibrary\__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.set_appium_timeout(timeout)
  File "<decorator-gen-36>", line 2, in set_appium_timeout
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AppiumLibrary\keywords\keywordgroup.py", line 15, in _run_on_failure_decorator
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AppiumLibrary\keywords\_applicationmanagement.py", line 121, in set_appium_timeout
    self._timeout_in_secs = robot.utils.timestr_to_secs(seconds)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\robottime.py", line 48, in timestr_to_secs
    raise ValueError("Invalid time string '%s'." % timestr)
```

[image]

Comment: How are you importing it?

Comment: In RIDE under Import library > Name "ExtendedAppiumLibrary"

Comment: According to its GitHub page, the library is in End of Life cycle for more than year and a half now; perhaps you'd consider using the official appium library (https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary), and see will this resolve it? You'd also get me community support with it.

Answer (score 0):

First hint is in the RF import error:

> FAILED ExtendedAppiumLibrary Initializing test library 'ExtendedAppiumLibrary' with no arguments failed: ValueError: Invalid time string 'Capture Page Scre
>   enshot'.

Let's see what docs says about initialization/importing lib to RF suite:
https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary/blob/master/docs/AppiumLibrary.html  (github does not render html so you need to save file on disk and load it to see in html rendered)

under importing section:

> run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot  ExtendedAppiumLibrary can be
>   imported with optional arguments.
>
> run_on_failure specifies the name of a keyword (from any available
>   libraries) to execute when a ExtendedAppiumLibrary keyword fails. By
>   default
>
> Capture Page Screenshot will be used to take a screenshot of the
>   current page. Using the value No Operation will disable this feature
>   altogether. See
>
> Register Keyword To Run On Failure keyword for more information about
>   this functionality.
>
> example: Library  ExtendedAppiumLibrary   run_on_failure=No Operation     # Does nothing on failure